# Finding Location of Duplicate Column

Tags: sql-server, duplicate-data

I have a table like following

```
Market   Date1  Date2 Date3 Date4 Duplicate

1068     $1     $2    $3     $4   3

1630     $5     $6    $7     $3   4

 190     $9    $10    $11    $12  0
```

i want to get number of Markets having duplicate sales of different dates and also the location of that duplicate in `Duplicate` Column. Here i added a column `Duplicate` to store the duplicate date column number. For example 1068 and 1630 have $3 duplicate sales. 1068 has $3 in `Date3` so a 3 should be placed in `Duplicate` Column similarly 4 goes in 1630 `Duplicate` column.

Comment: normalize your data to 3 columns, `market, price, date`

Comment: And what if a row has several duplicates? @DanielE.'s suggestion could help to eliminate that issue (in addition to being a more sensible design).